# angular http post values from the form

Tags: angular, http

I am new to coding and trying to post data using angular and swagger, I don't understand why it cannot retrieve the data.
It compiled well but it doesn't post the data and i get errors

below is my compoment code

```
signUp() {
  this.http.post<any>("https://localhost:7274/api/Login/CreateLogin", this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.signupForm.reset();
      this.router.navigate(['login'])
    }, (err: any) => {
      alert("something went wrong");
    });
}
```

below is my component.html codes

```
    <div> 
      <label for="validationDefault01" class="form-label" >First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"   formControlName="firstname" > 
    </div>
<br>

    <div>
      <label for="validationDefault02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="lastname" >
    </div>
   
    <div>
      <label for="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-label">E-mail</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"   aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2"  formControlName="email">
      </div>
  
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control"  formControlName="password"  > 
    </div>


    <div>
      <label for="validationDefault04" class="form-label">Gender</label>
      <select class="form-select" formControlName="gender"  >  
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
        <option selected>Select gender</option>
        <option >Male</option>
        <option >Female</option>
        <option >Do not prefer to answer</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid" id="submitBtn" >Register</button>  
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: You don’t seem to be doing anything with the response (res)?

Comment: Could you please post the errors you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Do something with the res. Try either `console.log(res)` or assign something to it like this `this.formData=res;`
Not forget to mention `formData:any`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).